React Native Expo SDK 52 Splash Screen
I am trying to create a splash screen. I am following the official documentation.
https://docs.expo.dev/develop/user-interface/splash-screen-and-app-icon/
and
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/#configuration
i am running prebuild and running in android emulator
the splash screen just appear as a small image in the center, how can i make it full screen?
here is my app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "my-app",
    "slug": "my-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "newArchEnabled": true,
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#232323"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#232323"
      },
      "package": "com.rasyidialwee.my-app"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png",
      "bundler": "metro"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router",
      "expo-font",
      [
        "expo-splash-screen",
        {
          "backgroundColor": "#232323",
          "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
          "dark": {
            "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
            "backgroundColor": "#232323"
          },
          "resizemode": "contain"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}


Did you find any solutions? I have same issue

Yes, I resolved it by changing the design to include only app logo, the background is stated in another parameter, or you could directly add the background in their own native editor.

From expo sdk 52, I have already enabled the newArchEnabled: "true".
the documentation link is this https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v52.0.0/sdk/splash-screen/#usage
You need to make use of same image for your splash screen, icon and favicon has your splash screen, either you insert the icon unto a plan image to center it. They already have figma template to do that for you or you make use of the webview splash-screen maker
I will suggest you go for this first link
https://www.figma.com/community/file/1155362909441341285
https://buildicon.netlify.app/
but if you still want to make use of different images for your icon and splash screen you will need to downgrade to v51. But your  expo go app won't work.

thank you for pointing this out, after reading the documentation, i notice the default style of splash screen now is displaying a logo on the center of the screen. While what i trying to achieve is to display a full screen image. But I change my design so it follow the default convention.

use resizeMode: "cover" instead of contain.
"splash": {
  "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
  "resizeMode": "cover",
  "backgroundColor": "#232323"
},


i tried this, but it still didn't change. Do i have to delete android folder, then run npx expo prebuild again?

If you are using dev client then you need to re-build your app or you can run:
npx expo run:android```
